# Python Gtk.Entry placeholder text

Tags: python, gtk, gtkentry

i have a login-window with two gtk.Entry objects, one for username, one for password. How can i add some Ghosttext to the Entry, so there is written "Username" in the Entry but if you click inside the text dissapears.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with Gtk+ 3.2 it's possible to [set placeholder text](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-placeholder-text).

```
entry = Gtk.Entry()
entry.set_placeholder_text("I am a placeholder")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found an [example](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TextEntries.html) where .set_text() and .select_region() are used to preselect the text, so it is deleted when the user starts to type.

This doesn't seem to work if you have more than one Gtk.Entry fields, because only one can be selected at a time. I reckon you have to use a signal to delete the text when the Entry field is clicked.

If you can't figure it out, add some labels.