# Is it possible to change the color of hint text of Text widget in SWT?

Tags: java, colors, textbox, swt

I would like to know if it is possible to change the color of hint text of a Text widget in SWT. 
I tried by setting the foreground color using `setForeground()` but hint text color remained same. Is there any workaround possible?

Comment: What is hint text?You can share screen-shot here http://imgur.com/

Comment: Hint text is something which gives a message to the user on what the field is for.
This is set using setMessage() method of Text widget.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected color of prompt/message in empty text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586772/selected-color-of-prompt-message-in-empty-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `setMessage()` method source code of Text widget. It uses the the foreground colour of the `place holder text` in the underlying OS. I don't know how to tweak it.

But you can:

Add focus listeners to Text Widget and use `setText()` and `setForeground()` methods to show or hide the message.

Refer [Selected color of prompt/message in empty text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586772/selected-color-of-prompt-message-in-empty-text-box) and [Python Gtk.Entry placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982799/python-gtk-entry-placeholder-text).